# Suppress warnings for javascript files under wwwroot/lib in .net core

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am running Visual Studio 2017 using a ASP.NET Core Web Application.

There are numerous warnings that come up for JavaScript files that were included as part of bower packages (under wwwroot\lib).

Is there any way to suppress all warnings from external packages -or- ignore files under wwwroot\lib.

Not sure if relevant but I am also using the Web Essentials 2017 Extension

I have already tried using the right click and suppress in suppression file as well as suppress in source and nether fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

They should dissapear, I had them also and suppressed them under project properties -> Build -> Errors and warnings: Suppress warnings. In that field but eg. JJ1234; JS4321; and so on.

Perhaps rebuilding would fix the "issue"?

Comment: I am looking to suppress errors in source code that is not mine (bower packages). I wan't to see if there are any issues in my code, so excluding by error type really doesn't solve the issue.